# Memory allocation for 2D array in C

Tags: c, memory-management, multidimensional-array, dynamic-arrays

I am writing a multithreaded C program and I have an error.
I have a 2D array `array worker_table` declared globally as:

```
int **worker_table;
```

And allocated  in main as follows:

```
worker_table        = (int**) calloc(number_of_workers*2,(sizeof(int)));
```

This is the worker function:

```
    void *Worker(void *worker_id)
    {

my_id = (int)worker_id;    //id of the worker
printf("Line 231\n");
printf("My id is %d\n",my_id);
my_customer = worker_table[my_id][1];//line 233
printf("Line 234\n");
int my id;
```

The error happens before line 234, I think what is wrong is on line 233, but I can't figure out what it is.

Comment: please provide a better headline for your question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your allocation is wrong. It should be like this:

```
worker_table = calloc(number_of_workers,(sizeof(int*)));
for(int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
{
   worker_table[i] = calloc(2, sizeof(int));
}
```

And the freeing procedure should be:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
{
    free(worker_table[i]);
}
free(worker_table);
```

I suggest that you should read [a good book on C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Answer (score 1):

You have only allocated one dimension of your 2d array.

This is how you can allocate the second dimension:

```
worker_table = malloc(number_of_workers * (sizeof(int*)));
for(size_t i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
  worker_table[i] = calloc(2, sizeof(int));
```

Or access it using some multiplication:

```
int* worker_table = calloc(number_of_workers*2,(sizeof(int)));
my_customer = worker_table[x + y * number_of_workers];
```